# how to multiply two different array of integers in python?

Tags: python

i have taken input in two different lists by splitting a line having integers 1 2

for eg
1 2

3 4

so now i have split it and kept it in lists , and want to multiply them like 1*3 +2*4, but when i try to do it , its giving me that it can only multiply integers and not lists !! 
help here

can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'.. that's the error i am getting –
when i do

```
c=sum(i*j for i, j in zip(a,b))
```

...

```
t=raw_input()
d =[]
for j in range(0,int(t)):
    c=0
    n=raw_input()
    s = raw_input()
    s1=raw_input()
    a=[]
    b=[]
    a.append( [int(i) for i in s.split(' ')])
    b.append([int(i) for i in s.split(' ')])
    d.append(sum(i*j for i, j in zip(a,b)))

for i in d:
    print i
```

that's my code

Comment: Post your code, since the sum(...) fragment is correct it must be that your splitting code is wrong.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 8):

You need:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [3,4]
>>> sum(i*j for i, j in zip(a,b))
11
```

Comment: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'.. thats the error i am getting

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a pythonic way using sum, map and a lambda expression.

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [3,4]
>>> prod = lambda a, b: a*b
>>> sum(map(prod, a, b))
11
```

the `lambda a, b: a*b` bit also has a special name in python, `operator.mul`

```
>>> import operator
>>> sum(map(operator.mul, a, b))
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
t=raw_input()
d =[]
for j in range(0,int(t)):
    #c=0
    #n=raw_input()
    s = raw_input()
    s1 =raw_input()
    a = [int(i) for i in s.split(' ')]
    b = [int(i) for i in s1.split(' ')] # <--s1 not s
    d.append(sum(i*j for i, j in zip(a,b)))

for i in d:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with multiplying integers, but you should probably be using the `extend` method:

```
    a.extend([int(i) for i in s.split(' ')])
    b.extend([int(i) for i in s.split(' ')])
```

`append` just tacks its argument on to the list as its last element. Since you are passing a list to `append`, you wind up with a list of lists. `extend`, however, takes the elements of the argument list and adds them to the end of the "source" list, which is what it seems like you mean to do.

(There are a bunch of other things you could do to fix up this code but that's probably a matter for a different question)